# center is not known element:html tag center not recognized angular 4

Tags: html, angular

center tag is not working saying center is not known element

```
<center>
    <a><img class="placeholder_img" src="img/placeholder.png"></a>
</center>
```

I used the above html tag saying that "center is not known element".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag expired and deprecated long back.

> **Obsolete**
>   This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Use `<div>` instead:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a><img class="placeholder_img" src="//placehold.it/100"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc

> The obsolete HTML Center Element () is a block-level element that displays its block-level or inline contents centered horizontally within its containing element. The container is usually, but isn'tt required to be, `<body>`.
>
> This tag has been deprecated in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1) in favor of the CSS text-align property, which can be applied to the  element or to an individual `<p>`. For centering blocks, use other CSS properties like margin-left and margin-right and set them to auto (or set margin to 0 auto).

Simply use the `div` tag instead of `center`